# Javascript: How can i 'announce' a function without calling it?

Tags: javascript, function, call

Can somebody help me?

The following code works, but unfortunately a function call to doSomething() is necessary:

```
<body onload=init()>
</body>

<script>
    function Startscreen()
    {
        this.doSomething(); //why is this call necessary and how else to solve it?
        this.startscreenhtml = 
            "   <form onsubmit=doSomething()>   " + 
            "       <input type=text />         " +
            "   </form>                         ";
        document.write(this.startscreenhtml);
    }
    Startscreen.prototype.doSomething = function()
    {
        alert(123)
    }
</script>

<script>
    function init()
    {
        var startscreen = new Startscreen();    
    }
</script>
```

I do want to keep function doSomething as a function of object Startscreen.

edit: i do want to keep using document.write

Preferrably i want to declare doSomething outside of the constructor as i am doing now, because i believe that otherwise if i would call new Startscreen multiple times, the same function is created multiple times.

However, i tried many things to make this work without the call to doSomething, including declaring the function inside the constructor, but nothing worked.
My guess is that the call is necessary to make the function known, because if the code is read top to down, im assigning it to 'onsubmit' before i declared it.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the code works as you think in the current form. The `doSomething` function will be called when you create the form, but it will not be called when you submit the form.

To call the function from the `onsubmit` event, it has to be known in the global context, as the event handler is not called in the context of the `Startscreen` instance. With your current code it's not possible to call the function for two reasons; it's not possible to reach from the global context, and as there is no reference left to the object instance there isn't even an instance left that you can use to call it.

(You could get the function from the prototype, or create a new instance of the object, but then your setup with an object would be completely pointless.)

If you want to keep the instance, you have to put it in a variable that survives the `init` function:

```
var startscreen;
function init() {
  startscreen = new Startscreen();    
}
```

Now the object will still be around when the `onsubmit` event handler is called, so you can reach the function via the variable:

```
this.startscreenhtml = 
  "<form onsubmit="startscreen.doSomething()">" + 
  "<input type=text />" +
  "</form>";
```

This is of course not ideal, as you couple the object to the variable, but I hope that you gained some knowledge about what's happening, so that you can come forward.

---

To use the method in the submit event without having a global variable to find it, you have to create an element so that you can hook up an actual function as the event handler. That way you can reach the method from the event handler:

```
// make a local variable that you can capture in a closure
var me = this;
var frm = document.createElement("form");
// make an anonymous function that will create a closure capturing "me"
frm.onsubmit = function(){
  me.doSomething();
};
```

This means that you can't use `document.write` to create the form (or you need to give each form a unique id so that you can get a reference to the created element and hook up the event afterwards).

Comment: Thanks very much for this solution, although it's not ideal yet as you say; i don't want to need to know beforehand what variable name i will be making. However, at first you say that my doSomething function will not be called when i submit the form... but it will be...? Just álso when creating the form (which is the side-effect i want to get rid of). Hope you will reply, and thanks for commenting

Comment: By the way, i get your explanation about there not being an (reference to an) instance left at the time the event handler does it's thing, but still the code does work (i test it in chrome). So maybe the initial call (which i want a different solution for) makes the instance known globally -implicitely- or lifts the function to the global level.. or i don't know im just guessing, but it works anyway... in the code as in my orginal post, the doSomething will be called when i submit

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't see how the `onsubmit` event could possibly call the method. Calling a method doesn't register is as a function in the global scope. You have to have some more code somewhere in the page that enables that. Anyway, I added some more above on how to reach the method from the event handler without a global variable.

Comment: I still see it working though... My original code can just be put in any .html file, and both chrome and IE will do doSomething on submit. Your added code is a workable solution, thanks. (Im terrible, but i still kind of have my heart set on the original appoach with 1 big string instead of createElement and stuff, because with 1 string its a little more readable and i call less functions, but mostly i still want to 'get' all this and not just go forward with the workable solution..)

Comment: Sorry but im going to put your answer as 'not useful' in the hope somebody can shed some light on this problem... Thanks very much for commenting though. I'll also edit my original post to include that i would like to use document.write, so that thís problem might get solved, instead of collecting (good, ty) other solutions.

Comment: @Jeroen: Does your actual code look like the one that you posted? You simply can't use `document.write` from code that is run from the `onload` event of the document, and then use something other than only the code that is written to the document. By using `document.write` after the document is already loaded, you will replace the entire document with the code that you write. Thus, when the `submit` event happend, your Javascript code doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @Jeroen: Here's a fiddle showing what's happening. The content in the page is replaced by the form, and when the `submit` event happens, the `startscreen` variable doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Yes, i can copy/paste exactly this code in a new document, give it extension .html, and both IE and chrome will start with 1 alert (which i dont want), and then give an alert on every submit

Comment: You forgot to put the link to the fiddle.. But still, copy pasting the code from my original post in a .html doc will work.. test and see..

Comment: @Jeroen: Sorry, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V5ueH/ I tested to put the code in an html file and run it. You don't get an alert when the `submit` event happens. What's happening is that submitting the form will reload the same page again, and the alert that you see is from the code that is writing the new form in the new page.